# forecasting arima in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I tried using the forecast package in R. When plotting the forecast for a number of samples in the future, I get a constant function. What is the reason of that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a FAQ and so much so that Rob Hyndman (who is the author of the [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) package) felt compelled to write an entire blog post about it: [flat forecasts](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/flat-forecasts/). Allow me to cite:

> It is pos­si­ble, even likely in some cir­cum­stances, that the future
>   obser­va­tions will have the same mean and then the fore­cast
>   func­tion is flat.
>
> - A ran­dom walk model will return a flat fore­cast func­tion (equal to the last observed value of the series).
> - An ETS(A,N,N) model will return a flat fore­cast function.
> - An iid model will return a flat fore­cast func­tion (equal to the mean of the observed data).
>
> This is not a bug. It is telling you some­thing about the time series
>   — namely that there is no trend, no sea­son­al­ity, and insuf­fi­cient
>   tem­po­ral dynam­ics to allow the future obser­va­tions to have
>   dif­fer­ent con­di­tional means.